# Using BuddyPress > 'Register page'

Tags: plugins, buddypress

Can someone help me figure out the Buddy Press plugin.

I have a magazine Wordpress website created with an open source theme and style and very slight html alterations and customizations.

I've downloaded all the necessary BuddyPress plugins:

**BuddyPress
BuddyPress Sliding Login Panel

BuddyPress Template Pack**

And it allows me to set/define pages for 'groups, members, and activity' but I cannot figure out how to implement a 'Register' page for people to register as that's the whole point of using the plugin. Now the screen where I "can" select which page to devote to register, no matter which I set it to, it just redirects to my home page. It allows me to create forms for a sign-up/register page, but can't implement it and get it to appear.

Can someone help?

*Cheers as always*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging out first, then going to the register page?

It won't show if you are logged in

Comment: Awesome, now I see it - just wondering why it didn't link in menu. I got thrown off because looking at BP compatibility > Under Navigational links > it states '(registration must be enabled)'

Comment: I, and others, have also been thrown by that in the past,   but it makes sense as that page is redundant if logged in....    Please accept the answer if you are happy?

Comment: Ah - I see. Now I've done a quick run through on a different email and it's all functional, though I can't find the 'login' page, any idea as where I can get that implemented?

Comment: I don't use the sliding login panel so can't really help on that question.  I have a login section in a sidebar which is default behaviour on the bp columns theme. Others have a login link on the buddybar.

Comment: Possibly a seperate Quesion - so if you know, I posted another Q here about it: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38197/buddypress-login-area

Comment: Oh - yeah, I'm not using a BP theme but keeping my custom one. Do you know a link that may bring me to a login/logout screen I could try to use to create a text link?